# Call js function using jsp form

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, jsp

So I have this problem that seems pretty simple but cant figure out what to do.
I'm trying to call a javascript method usign jsp form, like this:

```
<div class="form_user">
        <form:form id="coolForm" onSubmit="return functionToCall()" modelAttribute="userModel">

            <form:input type="hidden" id="tokenForgot" name="tokenForgot" path="tokenForgot" />
            <form:input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" path="Password" id="pwd" placeholder="password"/>
            <form:input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" path="password2" id="confirmpwd" placeholder="Confirm password"/>

            <button id="coolButton" >Submit</button>
        </form:form>
      </div>
```

The form goes to the JS method **functionToCall** and does what it needs to do (in the end is going to show a dialog and redirect afterwards). The thing is, after the JS method, it shows an error on the browser saying ***The method POST is not supported***. Apparently JSP adds a *action* and *method* attribute by default.

My question is,is there a way to stop JSP from doing this? or any workaround? Ofc I could do it using just `<form>` but I need the modelAttribute that JSP provides.

**EDIT 1:** 
Here is the JS method:

```
function functionToCall() {

var userForm = $("#coolForm").serialize();

var someService = new SomeService();

var result = someService.functionToCallPOST(userForm );

if (result.worked) {

    $("#dialogUser").dialog("open");
    $("#dialogText").text("Congratulations");
}
else {
    if (result.mensaje == "ERROR") {
        $("#dialogUser").dialog("open");
        $("#dialogUser").text("Error");
    }
    else {
        $("#dialogWarning").dialog("open");
        $("#dialogoTextW").text("enter your data again");
    }
}
```

}

The **functionToCallPOST** method is just straight AJAX calling the controller

Comment: share your **functionToCall** code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function functionToCall() does not return anything so your form get submit. try `return false`

```js
function functionToCall() {

var userForm = $("#coolForm").serialize();

var someService = new SomeService();

var result = someService.functionToCallPOST(userForm );

if (result.worked) {

    $("#dialogUser").dialog("open");
    $("#dialogText").text("Congratulations");
    return true;
}
else {
    if (result.mensaje == "ERROR") {
        $("#dialogUser").dialog("open");
        $("#dialogUser").text("Error");
    }
    else {
        $("#dialogWarning").dialog("open");
        $("#dialogoTextW").text("enter your data again");
    }
    
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: It works! Can't believe thats what it was, thank you